# Django + Vue with multiple apps

Tags: django, vue.js, dynamic, plugins, django-webpack-loader

There are plenty of tutorials and helpful posts how to use Django and Vue properly (in various options) all over the Internet.
But I didn't find a single one who describes **how to create a Django application which consists of more than one app, each having it's own part of the Vue frontend**.

I am creating a Django application with a Vue frontend, and it will have a lot of apps that can be plugged into the main system very easily (using a custom framework). But this only is the backend. I'd like to enable each Django app for having a "plugin" part of the frontend as well: e.g. a set of Vue components that are rendered "dynamically" in the frontend when this app is added in INSTALLED_APPS.

- How can I provide "plugin hooks" in Vue to load those components? All the things I have seen (dynamic/lazy component loading with webpack using webpack-loader, etc.) is not what I want. It only describes how to load a component that is predefined later in the http request timeline.
- How am I supposed to "merge" all the components? Can I simply create components in  static folders and let `./manage.py collectstatic` do the magic?

It doesn't matter if the application is a SPA or maybe I have to use Django templates (with Vue components included) - both would be a viable method.

Maybe this even is a webpack question and should be: How do I bring Vue (or React, etc) to collect its sources from different subdirectories like foo_app/static/, blah_app/static/, bar_app/static - is there a way to tell Vue/Webpack/etc to search in myproject/*/static for Vue components to merge?
And can I include "all components" (dynamical amount) than in another component, which is needed for such a system?

Can anyone enlighten me here - is that completely impossible? Or am I thinking in the wrong direction?

Thanks.

Comment: nobody knows an answer?? really? I'm always impressed that I'm the only one needing this?

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple of VueJS apps in my django site and I'm planning to add more.
I bundle them with webpack with the help of django-webpack-loader.
https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader

Comment: Eh - sure to use webpack-loader. But could you give an example how to "bundle" multiple Django apps' frontends to one global frontend? Because that's the question. I'll add that to my original question.

Comment: "a couple of VueJS apps" - what do you mean with VueJS apps? independent apps, all using the Django backend API? Or do you mean "Django apps with a VueJs frontend"?

Comment: I meant independent vue apps which are bootstrapped by django views/templates. And they used django APIs.
However I abandoned that approach. Currently I develop full vue apps (SPA or nuxt) and django is used as API server.

Comment: Ok, never seen that before, and that's exactly what I want. "Independent" Vue apps that are bootstrapped by Django templates. Have you got any code to share ;-) ?

Comment: I used django-webpack-loader.
On template bootstrap: https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader#templates

Each indipendent app is associated to a webpack project.
https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader#multiple-webpack-projects

Comment: I see. but this are, like you said, independent apps. So Django does the URL routing, and each app has it's own router for it's sub-URLs, right? AND, most interestingly: the apps don't interfere with each other, right? so no "plugin" system on the client side,  where some Vue apps use "hooks" from another Vue app?

Comment: No plugin system.
I did what django-webpack-loader allows to do.